# Reformulate an object with Lodash or other alternatives

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have this kind of object :

```
myObj= {a:[1,2,3,4], b:[4,5,6,7]}
```

and I want to convert it to an other one following this one:

```
myObj= [
      { name: a, items: [1,2,3,4]},
      { name: b, items: [4,5,6,7]}
   ];
```

Is that possible with `Lodash` ? I'm using it within `TypeScript` and I'm kind of new to it, any other ideas with `TypeScript` or native `JavaScript` will be welcomed, However I prefer it in `Lodash`.

Comment: btw I don't think what you are expecting to get is a real thing in javascript. What's it supposed to be? An object that's an  array of arays with a name property and an array property? My solution just returns an array with the transformed objects inside. I hope it's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no need to use lodash. You can have a clean solution with Typescript.

```
let modifiedObj = Object.keys(myObj).map(key => ({ name: key, items: myObj[key] }));
```

You can find a working example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20myObj%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%204%2C%205%5D%2C%20b%3A%20%5B7%2C%208%2C%208%2C%209%5D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20modifiedObj%20%3D%20Object.keys(myObj).map(key%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%20name%3A%20key%2C%20items%3A%20myObj%5Bkey%5D%20%7D))%3B).

Comment: Why do you call this "TypeScript"?

Comment: because of the arrow function.. although I admit it could be done the same in ES6 too.

Comment: The arrow function is not TypeScript. It **is** ES6.